# CSS circles with a number

Tags: html, css

I need to make bullets points like this:

[image: Bulletspoints]

I tried to think of anything how to do it, but the only thing I can think of is making it in photoshop, and make a img src tag. the best would be if it was ul and li tags.

Does anybody have a good idea how to do it?
I tried something like this, but it is not working properly:
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/8BPyS/)

**HTML**

```
<a href="abecadlo/"><div class="galeria">1</div></a>
<a href="abecadlo/"><div class="galeria">2</div></a>
<a href="abecadlo/"><div class="galeria">3</div></a>
```

**CSS**

```
.galeria{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: What exactly did you try already? Should this be an `ul`- or `ol`-element or something else?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was a little bit to quick there. I edited my question and posted the code that I tried, but it is not working the way I want. It is really amatuer made from my side.. :-/ But yes the best would be with ul and li tags.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a lot of approaches to realize this. Here's one:

- create a list (`ul` or `ol`) and remove the list style (`list-style: none;`)
- initialize a counter: `counter-reset: section;`
- increase counter on each list item and print it using a pseudo element (`:before`): `content: counter(section); counter-increment: section;`
- style the pseudo element (`:before`) like you want it

```css
ul {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  line-height: 40px;
}

li:before {
  content: counter(section);
  counter-increment: section;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
</ul>
```

**Further reading**

- [MDN: CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters)
- [MDN: Pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

**Demo**

[Try before buy](https://jsfiddle.net/zzor1m0b/)

Comment: That looks totally perfect. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do somethings as follow:

HTML

```
<a href="abecadlo/"><div class="galeria">1</div></a>
<a href="abecadlo/"><div class="galeria">2</div></a>
<a href="abecadlo/"><div class="galeria">3</div></a>
```

CSS

```
.galeria{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```